# Can I Use TraceIfFalse in deployment?

Tags: haskell, smart-contract, validator

So I use traceIfFalse to test a lot of my smart contracts now I'm ready to deploy some of then and I want to know if this is for development only or if its fine to have a smart contract use this function when deployed to the chain?

Im using it in the validator of the contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it strictly depends on your needs and how your validator is supposed to work.

traces in general (`trace`, `traceIfFalse`, `traceIfTrue`, `traceError`) [are known to be one of the causes of larger scripts](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/4174).

so if your validator has to be used in pair with other data in a transaction it is essential it reduces the script size.

keep in mind that removing traces means you'll likely have a hard time understanding what is wrong if something goes wrong.

one possible solution to keep traces would be to use error codes ( [as done for some errors that might happen when using builtin funcitonalities](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/plutus/troubleshooting.html#error-codes) ) so that you can reduce the script size and have a clue of what's going on in your code.